# Is there a way to use Rg.Plugins with Xamarin Forms Shell?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

From what I can see Xamarin Forms Shell is a "work in progress" and has been for a long time. With that in mind is there a way to use Rg.Plugins with Shell?

Having a problem doing things like this:

```
await Navigation.PushPopupAsync(PopupPage);
```

When there is no Navigation property with Shell.

Would appreciate any advice on what I can do, suggestions on another plugin that could help me or can I just do the same thing with my own custom code to open up another page?

For those people who have been in the same situation as me, what did you do?
now

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `Rg.Plugins` add support to Shell Navigation, this demand was added this to To Do in Todo List.
https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/issues/441,

But I test Rg.Plugins in the `ShellContent`,  `ShellContent` use a `ContentPage` to display the `Button`, then click the `Button` to pop up a window. it worked as normal. Here is running screenshot.

[image]

Xamarin forms shell achieve the Navigation that provide following ways.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation

I test `Rg.Plugins` with above ways. It cannot worked. It do not support the `Rg.Plugins` page.